# How to reference type definitions in inline scripts in vscode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

In an `index.html` file I am using ts type checking. This works fine for inline JSDoc declarations, ie. vscode correctly shows the invalid type assignment:

```html
<script>
// @ts-check

/**
 * @typedef {Object} SpecialType - a new type
 * @property {number} prop1 - a number
 */

/** @type {SpecialType} */
const x = { prop1: 'invalid number' }; // <-- vscode shows the type error
</script>
```

Is there any way to extract that type definition into an external file and import it in `index.html`, or make vscode otherwise aware of the type globally?

I tried the following, but in all cases vscode was missing the type when it was used in `index.html`:

- Create an external `types.js` file that just has the JSDoc typedef comment and import that via `<script src="..."></script>`
- Create an external `types.html` file that just has the script block with the JSDoc typedef comment and import that via `<link rel="import" href="...">`
- Create a `global.d.ts` file with the corresponding type and import it using `/// <reference path="..." />`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a typings folder, lets say, `typings/global`, to the root of your project. Then, create a `index.d.ts` file that contains your ts declarations, and place it inside `global` folder.

In your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"typeRoots": [
    {
       "./node_modules/@types"
       "./typings"
    }
],
"types": [
    "global",
    ...
]
```

**NOTE** [Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the types are still not available in the html file: [minimal sample](https://gitlab.com/a-xin/typescript-html-test/blob/master/index.html#L11)